# R deltaMethod(): Evaluating a combination of parameters when some levels of some parameters are not represented

Tags: r, regression

I'm running a linear regression with two categorical predictors and their interaction. One combination of levels does not occur in the data, and as expected, no parameter is estimated for it. I now want to significance test a particular combination of levels that does occur in the data (ie, I want to get a confidence interval for the total prediction at given levels of each variable).

In the past I've done this using `car::deltaMethod()` but in this dataset that does not work, as shown in the example below: The regression model gives the expected output, but deltaMethod() gives the error `error in t(gd) %*% vcov. : non-conformable arguments`. I believe this is because there is no parameter estimate for when the predictors have the values 't1' and 'other'. In the df_fixed dataframe, putting one person into that combination of categories causes `deltaMethod()` to work as expected.

I don't know of any theoretical reason that missing one interaction parameter estimate should prevent getting a confidence interval for a different combination of predictors. Is there a way to use `deltaMethod()` or some other function to do this without changing my data?

```
library(car)
# create dataset with outcome and two categorical predictors
outcomes <- c(91,2,60,53,38,78,48,33,97,41,64,84,64,8,66,41,52,18,57,34)
persontype <- c("t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t1","t2","t2","t2","t2","t1","t1","t2","t2","t1","t2","t2","t2")
arm_letter <- c("unsent","unsent","unsent","unsent","sent","unsent","unsent","sent","unsent","unsent","other","unsent","unsent","sent","unsent","other","unsent","sent","sent","unsent")
df <- data.frame(a = outcomes, b=persontype, c=arm_letter)

# note: there are no records with the combination 't1' + 'other'
table(df$b,df$c)


#regression works as expected
minimal_formula <- formula("a ~ b*c")
minimal_model <- lm(minimal_formula, data=df)
summary(minimal_model)

#use deltaMethod() to get a prediction for individuals with the combination 'b2' and 'sent'
# deltaMethod() fails with "error in t(gd) %*% vcov. : non-conformable arguments."
deltaMethod(minimal_model, "bt2 + csent + `bt2:csent`", rhs=0)

# duplicate the dataset and change one record to be in the previously empty cell
df_fixed <- df
df_fixed[c(13),"c"] <- 'other'
table(df_fixed$b,df_fixed$c)

#deltaMethod() now works
minimal_model_fixed <- lm(minimal_formula, data=df_fixed)
deltaMethod(minimal_model_fixed, "bt2 + csent + `bt2:csent`", rhs=0)
```